# Why Magento 2 developers create ASCII art in their code?

Tags: magento2, php

I wonder why nobody refactored this abomination

Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory

```
/**
 * Create object
 *
 * @param string $type
 * @param array $args
 *
 * @return object
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 *
 */
protected function createObject($type, $args)
{
    switch (count($args)) {
        case 1:
            return new $type($args[0]);
        case 2:
            return new $type($args[0], $args[1]);
        case 3:
            return new $type($args[0], $args[1], $args[2]);
        case 4:
            return new $type($args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3]);
        case 5:
            return new $type($args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3], $args[4]);
        case 6:
            return new $type($args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3], $args[4], $args[5]);
        case 7:
            return new $type($args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3], $args[4], $args[5], $args[6]);
        case 8:
            return new $type($args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3], $args[4], $args[5], $args[6], $args[7]);
        case 9:
            return new $type(
                $args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3], $args[4], $args[5], $args[6], $args[7], $args[8]
            );
        case 10:
            return new $type(
                $args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3], $args[4], $args[5], $args[6], $args[7], $args[8], $args[9]
            );
        case 11:
            return new $type(
                $args[0],
                $args[1],
                $args[2],
                $args[3],
                $args[4],
                $args[5],
                $args[6],
                $args[7],
                $args[8],
                $args[9],
                $args[10]
            );
        case 12:
            return new $type(
                $args[0],
                $args[1],
                $args[2],
                $args[3],
                $args[4],
                $args[5],
                $args[6],
                $args[7],
                $args[8],
                $args[9],
                $args[10],
                $args[11]
            );
        case 13:
            return new $type(
                $args[0],
                $args[1],
                $args[2],
                $args[3],
                $args[4],
                $args[5],
                $args[6],
                $args[7],
                $args[8],
                $args[9],
                $args[10],
                $args[11],
                $args[12]
            );
        case 14:
            return new $type(
                $args[0],
                $args[1],
                $args[2],
                $args[3],
                $args[4],
                $args[5],
                $args[6],
                $args[7],
                $args[8],
                $args[9],
                $args[10],
                $args[11],
                $args[12],
                $args[13]
            );
        case 15:
            return new $type(
                $args[0],
                $args[1],
                $args[2],
                $args[3],
                $args[4],
                $args[5],
                $args[6],
                $args[7],
                $args[8],
                $args[9],
                $args[10],
                $args[11],
                $args[12],
                $args[13],
                $args[14]
            );
        default:
            $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($type);
            return $reflection->newInstanceArgs($args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that implicitely means that there cannot be more than 15 args ?

Comment: ASCII Art? :') +1 for the funny question. I wonder who has a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Object Manager responsible for creating an object. But before PHP 5.6 we have only one way to create object and pass list of arguments.

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass($type);
$reflection->newInstanceArgs($args);
```

The problem with this method that we need create reflection object on each call that not best way from the performance point of view. As solution, we write code for most used variant with explicit argument passing and do not create reflection object in this case.

In  one of next releases, we plan to replace this construction with simple `return new $type(...$args);`

Comment: A little additional comment for @KAndy answer. Now, the minimal required version of PHP for Magento is 5.6, so this method was reworked to use [arguments unpacking](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php#L91)